# How to pass [(ng-model)] into @ViewChild in Angular4?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

I have a component that has `form` element inside it. This form has an `input[type="number"]` which will be used to adjust an `iframe` element. The problem is, the `iframe` element is inside `@ViewChild`. How do I pass the `[(ng-model)]` on the form input to the `[width]` on the `iframe` inside `@ViewChild`? The code looks something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "demo-iframe",
  template: `
  <form (submit)="onSubmit($event)">
    <input type="number" min="0" [(ngModel)]="model.px">px
    <button>update px</button>
  </form>
  <div #placeholder></div>
  `
})

export class DemoIframeCmp {
  @ViewChild("placeholder", { read: ViewContainerRef }) private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;


 constructor (
   private route: ActivatedRoute,
   private router: Router,
   private compiler: Compiler
 ) {
    document.title = "Test iframe";
    this.paramsSub = this.route.params.subscribe((params: IClickDemoParams) => {
      document.title = `Demo iframe ${params.demoId}`;
      this.buildDemo( params.demoId );
    });

    this.setWidth = 800;
   }


  private buildDemo (selector: string) {
    @Component({
      selector: "test-iframe",
      template: `
        <iframe class="iframe-demo" src="http://localhost:3000/${selector}" [width]="px"></iframe>
      `
    })

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting the `form` inside the child component. Also, instead of using `@Directive`, I use data-binding behavior of Angular. Something like this, but inside the `@ViewChild`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:
    <form #f="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit($event)">
      <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="model.px" name="px">px
      <button type="submit">adjust</button>
    </form>

    instant:
    <iframe [width]="model.px"></iframe>
    needs submit:
    <iframe [width]="px"></iframe>
})

export class App {
  model = {
    px: 10
  }

  px = 0

  constructor() {}

  onSubmit(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.px = this.model.px
  }
}

export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create an @Input() getter and setter in your child component:

```
_yourValue;
@Input() set yourValue(val) {
  this._yourValue = val;
}
get yourValue() {
  return this._yourValue;
}
```

This will act like ngModel for parent to child

Comment: Can you give a quick demo? Tried it but couldn't pass the value :(

Comment: This was the demo. You can pass a value to your child using the html notation: [yourValue]="value"